# Home Button Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to go back to the home screen but when I press the button the app collapses and there is no error or something in the log. What to do?

```
func goBack() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
}
```

Comment: This seems like logical behavior.... What exactly would you like to happen when the user presses the home button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by "go back to home screen" you mean move to another skscene. I'll assume you're moving to GameScene.

```
var scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
var transition = SKTransition.flipVerticalWithDuration(1.0)
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
self.scene!.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just add a button over the GameScene in the Storyboard view and segue it to the other GameScene or the main storyboard.

I hope this helps :)